# Remove option "Relevance" from sort by

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, position, product-sorting

When I do any search we can see a list of products with the field "Sort by", but I need get rid of the option "Relevance":
[image]

If I go to a category from menu I don't have this sorter.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove relevance sort order in searching you can rewrite below class

`app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php`

`Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result` in your custom module

and rewrite this method in this class `setListOrders`

and comment below code

```
 $availableOrders = array_merge(array(
        'relevance' => $this->__('Relevance')
    ), $availableOrders);
```

Comment: @str_lml , You are always welcome  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sort options are set in [`Mage_CatalogSearch_Block_Result::setListOrders()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php#L108-L125)

To override this you can add something like this to your `local.xml`

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setAvailableOrders">
            <sort>
                <name>Name</name>
                <price>Price</price>
            </sort>
         </action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

This would give you 2 sorting options (Name and Price). You can also use a helper method to make it more flexible ...

---

**Edit:** bit more flexible ... you dont have to care about other sort options, it just removes `relevance`:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setAvailableOrders">
            <sort helper="[your_helper]/removeRelevanceFromSortOptions" />
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

For you helper you can use this:

```
public function removeRelevanceFromSortOptions()
{
    $availableOrders = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
        ->getCurrentCategory()
        ->getAvailableSortByOptions();

    unset($availableOrders['position']);
    # no need to to this ... see setListOrders()
    # unset($availableOrders['relevance']);

    return $availableOrders;
}
```

Comment: Bro I think Op ask for search , not for category

Comment: You always welcome bro :) , but how we can remove one sorting with this, because , Relevance is hard coded in PHP code over there

Comment: but +1 for this answer as I am not aware of it

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala You do not remove one particular item, you (re-)set all sort options.

Comment: @sv3n Yes, But I only need remove one sorting.

Comment: @str_lml I know ... updated my answer b/c I don't like rewrites :)

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala dont understand why its hardcoded, but using helper lets you remove single options.